# Using mysql: How to add unique id for the same data in another colmun

Tags: mysql

How do I insert unique Ids to `car_id` column as seen on table below?

```
|car_id|     CarId  |
+------+------------+
|  1   |      1234  |
|  1   |      1234  |
|  1   |      1234  |
|  2   |      5678  |
|  2   |      5678  |
|  2   |      5678  |
|  3   |    9101112 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Use variables:

```
   SELECT CarId, 
          @seq := IF(@cid = CarId, @seq,
                    IF(@cid := CarId, @seq + 1, @seq + 1)) AS car_id
   FROM mytable
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @seq := 0, @cid := 0) AS vars 
   ORDER BY CarId
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bff7b/2)